# how to fetch related items in django many to many relation

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In the list l , I need the departments list associated with a particular employee , but it throws
'User' object has no attribute 'dep__department'

```
    class Dep(models.Model):
        department = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    
    
    class EMP(models.Model):
        id = ShortUUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
        email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email address", max_length=255, unique=True)
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        dep = models.ManyToManyField(Dep)
```

views.py

```
       l=[]
       users=EMP.objects.filter(some filter condition)
       for d in users:
         l.append(d.dep__department)
```

Comment: You don't provide the user model so I'm guessing it doesn't have a Dep attribute as the error suggests

Comment: @Someprogammer sorry my fault , it is EMP.objects.filter(some filter condition) , but the error still persists

Comment: Please accept an answer if your problem is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d.dep should be directly instances of your department class so you can get the department name directly through d.dep.department.

Edit:
you can iterate through the instances using `d.dep.all()`

So your code becomes:

```
l=[]
users=EMP.objects.filter(some filter condition)
for d in users:
   for dep in d.dep.all():
      l.append(dep.department)
```

Comment: tried it , now it throws " ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute department"

Comment: Yes, sorry d.dep is a queryset of instances of Department, you can iterate through them using d.dep.all(). Then for those instance you can get their attributes such as department.

Comment: d.dep is not iterable, you probably mean something like for dep in d.dep.all():

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `d.dep.all()` to get all dep in your user.

Comment: tried it , now it throws " ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute department"

Comment: I edited my comment, is this what you are tring?

Comment: I missed that dep was a ManyToMany, d.dep is a manager so you should use all() or filter() to get the departement you are looking for